# How to evaluate how well one knows functional programming

Tags: learning, self-improvement, functional-programming

I've been wondering how to determine if I *know* functional programming.
By know I mean in a Journeyman sense, not a master, but competent enough to do the work.

I like languages w/ query/data shaping constructs built in, but is knowing the ins and outs of maps, filters, and aggregates in the form of  `Linq`, `Sql`, and `Reactive Extensions` sufficient to claim that one knows functional programming? Or are additional specific concepts and skills required?

Edit: I've been working in OO and languages that identify primarily as OO langs for 15 years. As I'm not in an env that is self-identified as functional, there's little to measure against.

Is avoiding immutable state and knowing how to use `fold` all there is?

Comment: Try writing something nontrivial in Haskell. If you can figure your way out, you're there.

Comment: Excellent question! voting up.

Comment: Federico, must it be Haskell, what's an example of nontrival?

Comment: Is evaluating how well someone knows functional programming any different than evaluating how well someone knows object-oriented programming, procedural programming, or aspect-oriented programming?

Comment: @Federico: your comment would make a very good answer if more detail was added.

Comment: Subscribe to `functional-programming` on SE and see how many questions you can answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dakotah's answer is important and I would like to add a couple of things:

- Understanding Monads.
- Understanding Tail call optimization (TCO) and why it does matter  and how the language in question implements it.
- Understanding persistent data structures and how to implement a one by hand.

I'm pretty sure there are a lot of things, please feel free to complete the list.

Answer (score 3):

The first step to be able to recognize the difference between imperative and functional styles in code. For example, Odersky in Programming in Scala highlights that one telltale sign is

> that if code contains any vars [variables in Scala that can be
>   modified] is is probably imperative style. If the code contains no vars at all--i.e., it contains only vals--it is probably in a functional style. One way to move towards a functional style, therefore, i s to try to program without vars.

For example, consider this while loop:

```
var i = 0
while (i < args.length) {
   println(args(i))
   i+=1
}
```

The var is the sign it is imperative. This is Scala would become

```
def printargs(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    args.foreach(println)
}
```

But this code isn't purely functional yet because it has side effects.

From a functional point of view this should be:

```
def formatArgs(args: Array[String]) = args.mkString("\n")
```

So ... to determine if you know functional programming, are you writing code without the equivalent of vars and no local side effects!?